# Can failing to install an npm package result in a ENOTEMPTY error?

Tags: npm, webpack

I've installed an npm package but my connection must have dropped in the meantime, the installation failed, and now I'm getting an error message. When I try to reinstall, my log file says the following:

```
1256 error code ENOTEMPTY
1257 error syscall rename
1258 error path /Users/joaomarrucho/Trabalho/2022/Float-in/float-in-2/node_modules/@babel/runtime
1259 error dest /Users/joaomarrucho/Trabalho/2022/Float-in/float-in-2/node_modules/@babel/.runtime-wHPFKKjx
1260 error errno -66
1261 error ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/joaomarrucho/Trabalho/2022/Float-in/float-in-2/node_modules/@babel/runtime' -> '/Users/joaomarrucho/Trabalho/2022/Float-in/float-in-2/node_modules/@babel/.runtime-wHPFKKjx'
1262 verbose exit -66
```

I have both `.runtime` file and `.runtime-wHPFKKjx` so I can't rename the runtime file to the file name suggested. I don't want to do anything stupid. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just delete package-lock.json file and then install package what you want all will works

Comment: Thanks @m.hedayat ! So if delete package-lock.json will I not have to reinstall all the other packages as well?

Comment: No , you shouldn't